# Android: How do I encrypt with fingerprint protected secret key right after generating it?

Tags: android, security, encryption, fingerprint

I'm trying to encrypt a PIN using my fingerprint. My plan is to have a setting in my Settings activity to activate the fingerprint protection.

Once the user turns the setting on, he/she will be asked to enter their PIN which will then be encrypted with a secret key linked to their fingerprint.

As per [Google's android-FingerprintDialog sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog), I created a secret key linked to my fingerprint and am trying to use it right away after generating it to encrypt my PIN but I'm getting `android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated` when calling `cipher.doFinal()`.

It looks like I'll have to not only ask the user to enter the PIN but also ask them to authenticate once with their fingerprint to encrypt the PIN which impacts the user experience a bit.

Is there any way I can encrypt the PIN with the secret key right after generating it without requiring users to authenticate the first time around?

Please see my code below. Thanks.

```
    public void createKey(String keyName, boolean invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment) {
        // The enrolling flow for fingerprint. This is where you ask the user to set up fingerprint
        // for your flow. Use of keys is necessary if you need to know if the set of
        // enrolled fingerprints has changed.
        try {
            mKeyStore.load(null);
            // Set the alias of the entry in Android KeyStore where the key will appear
            // and the constrains (purposes) in the constructor of the Builder

            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    // Require the user to authenticate with a fingerprint to authorize every use
                    // of the key
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);

            // This is a workaround to avoid crashes on devices whose API level is < 24
            // because KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment is only
            // visible on API level +24.
            // Ideally there should be a compat library for KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder but
            // which isn't available yet.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                builder.setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment);
            }
            mKeyGenerator.init(builder.build());
            SecretKey secretKey = mKeyGenerator.generateKey();

            if (initEncryptionCipher(mDefaultEncryptionCipher, secretKey))
                tryEncrypt(mDefaultEncryptionCipher, SECRET_MESSAGE);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                | CertificateException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the {@link Cipher} instance with the created key in the
     * {@link #createKey(String, boolean)} method.
     *
     * @param secretKey the key name to init the cipher
     * @return {@code true} if initialization is successful, {@code false} if the lock screen has
     * been disabled or reset after the key was generated, or if a fingerprint got enrolled after
     * the key was generated.
     */
    private boolean initEncryptionCipher(Cipher cipher, SecretKey secretKey) {
        try {
            mKeyStore.load(null);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return true;
        } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
            Log.e("Encryption Cipher", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            return false;
        } catch (CertificateException | IOException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Tries to encrypt some data with the generated key in {@link #createKey} which is
     * only works if the user has just authenticated via fingerprint.
     */
    private void tryEncrypt(Cipher cipher, String secret) {
        try {
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(secret.getBytes());
            SECRET_MESSAGE = new String(Base64.encode(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT));
        } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to encrypt the data with the generated key. "
                    + "Retry the purchase", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
```

Comment: If "so the code is a bit messy" clean it up, especially if you want others to understand it.

Comment: _"Is there any way I can encrypt the PIN with the secret key right after generating it without requiring users to authenticate the first time around?"_. No. `setUserAuthenticationRequired` means **every** use of the key must be authorized using fingerprint authentication. There's a [setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.html#setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(int)) method which allows the key to be used multiple times within a given timespan after the device is unlocked...

Comment: (continued) ...but I don't know if it applies to newly created keys.

Comment: @Michael thanks. That's what I have found so far too. It's just I found a similar question on Stackoverflow where the accepted answer is similar to the above code (i.e. the code uses the generated key right away). Looks like it can't be used this way. Care to post your comment as an answer so that I can approve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` with no validity duration specified means:

> Each operation involving such a key must be individually authorized by the user. Currently, the only means of such authorization is fingerprint authentication

That includes the first operation after creating the key.

---

`KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder` has another method, [`setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(int)) which allows you to specify that the key should be usable for an unlimited number of operations during N seconds after the latest authorization. Keys for which you have specified a validity duration also has this slightly different property:

> All keys in this mode are authorized for use as soon as the user unlocks the secure lock screen or confirms their secure lock screen credential using the `KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent` flow

However, I don't know if this applies to newly created keys - i.e. whether a newly created key instantly becomes usable, or if that doesn't happen until the *next* time the user unlocks the screen.

---

([source](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#UserAuthentication))